# How to linearize the product of two float variables

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I would like linearizate the product of two float variables. Suppose that a model has the product x * y, where x and y are float, with 0 <= x <= 1 and 0 <= y <= 1. How linearizate this product?

Comment: What do you mean by linearize? Or was it linearizate?

Comment: Also, what language? Cplex offers a number of alternatives to my understanding, and float can mean different things.

Comment: I am building a mathematical model on cplex, using c++, and I would like linearizate a constraint that has the product of two continuous variables. I have a constraint  x * y (product of two variables),  where domain this variable are 0 <= x <= 1 and 0 <= y <= 1. Linearizate is to transform this expression (x * y) into something that does not exist the multiplication of two variables

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have you actually tried anything or done any research of your own?

Comment: I don't think you can exactly linearise that. You can approximate it with e.g. piecewise linear expressions.

Comment: Quadratic solvers are developed for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

I gave an example in OPL/CPLEX [here](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/multiply2float.mod)
What you can do is remember that

```
4*x*y=(x+y)*(x+y)-(x-y)(x-y)
```

So if you do a variable change X=x+y and Y=x-y

```
x*y
```

becomes

```
1/4*(X*X-Y*Y)
```

which is separable.

And then you are able to interpolate the function x*x by piecewise linear function:

```
// y=x*x interpolation



int sampleSize=10000;
float s=0;
float e=100;

float x[i in 0..sampleSize]=s+(e-s)*i/sampleSize;

int nbSegments=20;

float x2[i in 0..nbSegments]=(s)+(e-s)*i/nbSegments;
float y2[i in 0..nbSegments]=x2[i]*x2[i];

float firstSlope=0;
 float lastSlope=0;
 
 tuple breakpoint // y=f(x)
 {
  key float x;
  float y;
 }
 
 sorted { breakpoint } breakpoints={<x2[i],y2[i]> | i in 0..nbSegments};
 
 float slopesBeforeBreakpoint[b in breakpoints]=
 (b.x==first(breakpoints).x)
 ?firstSlope
 :(b.y-prev(breakpoints,b).y)/(b.x-prev(breakpoints,b).x);
 
 pwlFunction f=piecewise(b in breakpoints)
 { slopesBeforeBreakpoint[b]->b.x; lastSlope } (first(breakpoints).x, first(breakpoints).y);
 
 assert forall(b in breakpoints) f(b.x)==b.y;
 
 float maxError=max (i in 0..sampleSize) abs(x[i]*x[i]-f(x[i]));
 float averageError=1/(sampleSize+1)*sum (i in 0..sampleSize) abs(x[i]*x[i]-f(x[i]));
 
 execute
{
writeln("maxError = ",maxError);
writeln("averageError = ",averageError);
}

dvar float a in 0..10;
dvar float b in 0..10;
dvar float squareaplusb;
dvar float squareaminusb;

maximize a+b;
dvar float ab;
subject to
{
    ab<=10;
    ab==1/4*(squareaplusb-squareaminusb);
    
    squareaplusb==f(a+b);
    squareaminusb==f(a-b);
}
```

Comment: How is this linearized?

Comment: See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/multiply2float.mod in https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/